# Valid HTML in Template Part

Tags: templates, get-template-part

in a custom plugin I have a WPQuery, which looks like the following:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'mission',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post__not_in' => $sticky,
        'posts_per_page' => $count
    );

    $latest_missions = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $latest_missions->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $latest_missions->have_posts() ) {
            $latest_missions->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content-list', get_post_format() );
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

and the corresponding template part:

```
<li  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> " class="future-event"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
```

The only problem I have is, that this will no produce semantic correct HTML, because the list is not sematically correct.

Is there a way, how I can create an `<ul></ul>` which is wrapped around the list, when my loop is finished?

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is. Just do it like this:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'mission',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post__not_in' => $sticky,
    'posts_per_page' => $count
);

$latest_missions = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $latest_missions->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';  // prints opening ul tag before list items
    while ( $latest_missions->have_posts() ) {
        $latest_missions->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content-list', get_post_format() );
    }
    echo '</ul>';  // prints closing ul tag after list items

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```